# I need to rewrite this sentence while keeping the same meaning and starting with the given word(s)

Tags: meaning, grammar

> - Paul and Jane moved to Paris two years ago.
> - It is...

If the starting words were "it has" I could have written "It has been two years since...". But the auxiliary "be" is used instead and I am not allowed to change it. I don't have a single idea what the solution might be.

Comment: Why do you have to use "it is" instead of "it has been"? That's much more preferable. "It has been two years since Paul and Jane moved to Paris.".

Comment: @Kace36 because the exercise is testing the student's knowledge. These are typical exam prep questions, you cannot change the words supplied, that would be too easy!

Comment: It is Paris. Two years later. Paul and Jane are still unpacking.

Answer (score 24):

"It is **two years since** Paul and Jane moved to Paris." is still correct, even though less common.

For example, have a look at [this quote by Sally Brampton](https://books.google.ae/books?id=xqLirBgEC-UC&pg=PT9&lpg=PT9&dq=%E2%80%9CIt%20is%20two%20years%20since%20I%20emerged%20from%20depression%20and%20I%20no%20longer%20want%20myself%20dead.%22&source=bl&ots=wybdynHYbH&sig=Rjz5gT_vStg-jRQJyknoe59aGEA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9CIt%20is%20two%20years%20since%20I%20emerged%20from%20depression%20and%20I%20no%20longer%20want%20myself%20dead.%22&f=false) (which is the best example Google spewed out at a quick glance — I'm sure there are many more to find)

> It is two years since I emerged from depression and I no longer want myself dead.
>   I want myself alive.

You might also want to have a look at *English Grammar in Use : a reference and practice book for intermediate students of English* by Raymond Murphy.

Comment: Alright @Mari-LouA, I did as you ordered. The link did indeed provide an excerpt. But who knows how long Google might have kept up the link anyway.

Comment: I tried that, but it's a scan, so no c&p. I added the title, though

Comment: Agree with this. A small variant where "_It is..._" would be more natural (though not necessarily true in this case) could be "_It is two years **to the day** since Paul and Jane moved to Paris_".

Comment: You're getting so many upvotes that I think it's worth the effort to...manually (eek!)  type the explanation. "It is [time] since" is rather old fashioned, but it is still common in British English.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I totally agree as well.

Comment: Might I also suggest "It is _now_ two years since..."?

Comment: @LiveMynd - Might I suggest reading [other answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/136001/11145)?

Comment: Ah, _mea culpa_, though I don't know how I missed that one.

Answer (score 13):

As Sprottenwels says in their [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/135996/11145) (emphasis mine):

> "It is two years since Paul and Jane moved to Paris." is still correct, *even though less common*.

You could make this more common by inserting the word **now**:

> It is **now** two years since Paul and Jane moved to Paris

Answer (score 6):

AndyT's variation on Sprottenwels' answer is probably the most natural sounding, but I'll offer this alternative (which is similar to a comment by Jim)

> It is Paris to which Paul and Jane moved two years ago

This variant emphasises Paris (i.e. where they moved to) rather than the two years (i.e. when they moved), which might be desirable depending on the context. However, it's a slightly old-fashioned construction. The only similar quote I could find was from Jean Paul Sartre in his essay "[What is Literature](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ROjKHbAnXFwC&pg=PT86&lpg=PT86&dq=%22it%20is%20paris%20to%20which%22&source=bl&ots=90nH9zoKgF&sig=rNJT3gA28JZ7AsLZtbOV7rVgiHc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvrdvSrIHVAhUqKcAKHTszAvMQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22it%20is%20paris%20to%20which%22&f=false)":

> It is Paris to which writers from the provinces, if they are well-off, come to practise regionalism

Comment: To be honest this sounds more natural to me. "It is two years since" feels _very_ odd (even though it's not _technically_ wrong)

Answer (score 5):

> It is the case that Paul and Jane moved to Paris two years ago.

There are many ways in which English speakers, and even writers, extend sentences without materially altering the meaning. Any assertion may be prefaced with one of these:

- It is true that ...
- Believe me when I say ...
- Actually ...
- The fact is ...
- I can tell you ...
- It is the case that ...

In using the latter, the speaker probably feels that the added phrase lends a note of authority or formality. It is often used when alternatives to the assertion have been suggested or implied.

Comment: I deleted my answer when I read this one more carefully (as mine was redundant).  So I suppose +1 is only appropriate.  By the way, if "It is true that Paul and Jane moved to Paris two years ago" is not considered to be a different enough re-write, consider: "
 
If that's not "enough" of a re-write, then: "It is true that two years ago is when Jane and Paul relocated their residence to be in France's capital."

Comment: "It is a fact that Paul and Jane moved to Paris two years ago."

Answer (score 1):

Just to demonstrate that there are several ways to solve this problem, here's another one in idiomatic English.

> It is the third year that Paul and Jane have spent living in Paris.

You can't change the verb, but you still have a ton of flexibility since the subject of the sentence hasn't been nailed down for you.

Answer (score -2):

Just wondering, can't you use this?

> It is two years ago when Paul and Jane moved to Paris.

Should "was" be used after "It"?

Comment: Yes. 1234567890